# Principle of Extension proof of the empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a text I see

> Two sets are equal if they have the same members. That is, $x = y \iff \forall z \; [(z \in x) \iff (z \in y)]$

Then it says

> Let $e_1$ and $e_2$ be empty sets. Then for all elements $z$, the statements $z
>  \in e_1$ and $z \in e_2$ are both false; hence, they are logically
> equivalent, and $e_1 = e_2$ by the Principle of Extension.

This seems to be a sleigh of hand. $(z \in x) \iff (z \in y)$ should be $True \iff True$ thus PoE holds. How can we say $(z \notin e_1) \iff (z \notin e_2)$, therefore, $False \iff False\;$ PoE also holds?

Comment: How can we not?  Surely $False \iff False$ must be a trued statement.  If false is true, then false is true.  So $false \implies false$... And vice versa $false \Leftarrow false$ so $false \iff false$ *must* be true.  And sure $(A\iff B) \iff (\lnot A \iff \lnot B)$ must be a true statement.  If the only way $A$ can only be true if be is then $A$ can only be false if $B$ is.  And vice versa... and all logic aside how can empty sets ever be different.  If a set has no elements at all then it is exactly the same as any other set with no elements. They can't be different.

Comment: Two states are *equivalent* if the yield the same truth table.  The truth table for $z\in e_1$ is $FALSE$. That's it. its a table with one row in it.  and the row is $FALSE$. And $x\in e_2$ truth table is also $FALSE$.  They are exactly the same.... Would it make it easier to think that there can only be one empty set.  If a set is defined as having no elements there is only one way it can be: For everything that is... don't put it in the set. There is only one way to do that so there is only one empty set.  So if $e_1$ and $e_2$ are empty $e_1 = e_2$.

Comment: See your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488488/zf-axiom-of-extensionality-implies-unique-determination)